# \mathrlap type instruction but only 'locally'

Tags: positioning

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{a',a'' \in \mathscr{A}} c_{a'}^* \, c_{a''}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

results in this output:

[image].

I want the c's to start right after the sum sign, i.e. ignoring the subscript. If I encapsulate the subscript within \mathrlap{} from mathtools, however, it also messes up the placement of the sum sign. Thus, in essence, I want an instruction for the c's to ignore the vertical spread of the sum's subscript, but not the sum sign itself.

Comment: Look at `\smashoperator` in the manual of `mathtools`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mathtools` package provides a macro called `\smashoperator` along with two variants, `\smashoperator[l]` and `\smashoperator[r]`. I think you want either `\smashoperator[r]` or `\smashoperator`.

[image]

If you look closely at the code in lines 2 and 3 of the `align*` environment, you'll see that I also advocate replacing `c_{a''}` with `c^{}_{a''}` (to align the subscript term with the one in `c_{a'}^*`) and `a',a''\in\mathscr{A}` with `a'\!,a''\in\mathscr{A}` (for a slightly "tighter" look).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x&=\sum_{a',a''\in\mathscr{A}} c_{a'}^* \, c_{a''}\\
x&=\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a'\!,a''\in\mathscr{A}}} c_{a'}^* \, c^{}_{a''}\\
x&=\smashoperator{\sum_{a'\!,a''\in\mathscr{A}}} c_{a'}^* \, c^{}_{a''}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```